# Spring Integration Error Handling with Email Once at end

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How do I handle errors thrown in the below SpringIntegrationFlow just by logging the error and continuing with the next record. As well should be able to send an email only once irrespective of 1 or more records failed. Is there something equivalent of Spring Batch's StepListener? Thanks

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(), p -> p.poller(pollerSpec()))
                       .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, appErrorChannel()))
                       .split()
                       .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                       .transform(transformer, "transform")
                       .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                       .handle(Http.outboundGateway(url)
                                   .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                   .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                                   .requestFactory(requestFactory))
                       .get();

@Bean
public MessageChannel appErrorChannel() {

    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean("appErrorFlow")
public IntegrationFlow appErrorFlow() {

    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())
                            .log(Level.ERROR, message -> " Failed Message " + message.getPayload())
                            .aggregate(a -> a.correlationStrategy(m -> !m.getHeaders().isEmpty()))
                            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(mailURL)
                                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))
                            .get();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

**Exception:**

```
2022-01-13 06:41:31,702 [Worker-1                  ] WARN  o.s.i.c.MessagePublishingErrorHandler - 005006f2dee5b673 Error message was not delivered.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=*******Removed On Purpose*******]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:96)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest equivalent for `StepListener` is a `ChannelInterceptor`.

See `IntegrationFlowDefinition.intercept()` operator to place in between your endpoints in that flow.

However according your splitter configuration, it doesn't seem like you are going to lose anything and errors are just going to be logged. That `c.executor()` does the trick to shift the work for each record into a thread pool and its error cannot effect the rest of records.

Anyway it sounds like better for you to have a custom error channel be set into headers just before that `split()` - `.enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, myErrorChannel()))`.

Than you have an aggregator subscribed to this channel where you aggregate errors for the batch and emit a message to send an email. This is going to happen really only once per batch or none at all if no errors.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my queries. Over the internet I find few example for DSL as compared with the XML configuration. That's where finding it difficult as DSL abstracts the channel which is a necessary configuration in XML. Once again, thanks for answering my (newbie) various questions on Spring IntegrationFlow DSL

Comment: Just for a future usecase, If I were to send an email on the successful completion with no errors (with threadpool) of the IntegrationFlow, where should it be?

Comment: Similar `aggregate()` in the end of your flow. Just after that `.handle(Http.outboundGateway(url))`!

Comment: Apologies, was there a reason you did not suggest to use the default "errorChannel" as it would have handled the logging by default through the "loggingHandler" and we could have aggregated the messages from "errorChannel"? How do we specify the channelname in the aggregator?

Comment: Yes, you can. But that is a global channel which may use by default in many other flows in your application. So, you may accidentally try to aggregate errors from wrong places. The `IntegationFlow` may start from a channel. The `aggregate()` could be used as an endpoint in that flow. Following by the `handle(Mail.outboundAdapter())`

Comment: Im missing a basic, seeing `org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers` with the updated code. Also, when tried with `from("errorChannel")` pointing to the global errorChannel it works, however the aggregator is expecting Correlation Strategy. Why is that so?

Comment: That exception probably has an info about the channel you are missing the subscriber. Also: try just `return new DirectChannel();` for that `appErrorChannel` bean definition. No reason to use a factory. Plus: see if you can use a `IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())` instead of a name.

Comment: Have removed the factory for `new DirectChannel()`, still the subscriber error is thrown when custom `appErrorChannel()` is used. Please see the complete stack trace on the updated question.

Comment: Looks like your `@Configuration` come with the `proxyBeanMethods=false`. Just because it doesn’t show that your `appErrorChannel()` method call returns a bean when you call it from those flows definitions.

Comment: Bummer, my bad. It understands the `appErrorChannel()` bean now even with the Factory method. Isn't the Factory method equivalent of `new DirectChannel()`? One last thing on this question, why is my aggregation expecting a `CorrelationStrategy` and simply not perform an aggregation --> `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing`?

Comment: Yes, it is an equivalent , but it is not responsible for bean creation, neither for dependency injection . You have to look into a `failedMessage` of the `MessagingException` in the payload of that `ErrorMessage` sent to that channel.

Comment: Pls comment on the aggregation behavior which is expecting a CorrelationStrategy

Comment: That’s what I did. The correlation cannot be done on the error message: you have to extract the content of that error . And I said you what to look for. The correlation details is populated into headers by the splitter. But that info is the part of failed message - the one inside an exception of the error message